# UIImagePickerController camera not working swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an action sheet that has two options: one where you can choose an image from your library and one where you can take a photo from the camera. The photo library functions properly, but I can't seem to get the camera to work.

Here is my code:

```
let takePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Take photo", style: .Default,   handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    // present camera taker
    var cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraPicker.delegate = self
    cameraPicker.sourceType = .Camera
    self.presentViewController(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)   
})

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    var selectedAvatar = UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem, can anybody help me out? The program crashes when I try to run it and click on Take Photo.

Comment: Whats happening? Does it crash? Doesnt anything happen at all? Please always  provide what is happening than just "not working"

Comment: I just did, my apologies.

Comment: Please provide more information about what error? Crashing with what error? anything logged?

Comment: If you're using the simulator it will always crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely running in the simulator. The simulator dont have a camera so to not make the app crash when pressing the button you have to check if cemera is available.

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
    ...
}
else {
    print("Sorry cant take picture")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below code

```
func takePhoto()
{
  if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
  {
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  else
  {
    let alertWarning = UIAlertView(title:"Warning", message: "You don't have camera", delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"OK", otherButtonTitles:"")
    alertWarning.show()
  }
}
func openGallary()
{
  picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
  self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//PickerView Delegate Methods
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
  picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
  println("picker cancel.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why the camera can crash when used in a real device as Kirit Modi said in the following tread:

[iOS 10 - App crashes To access photo library or device camera via UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738804/ios-10-app-crashes-to-access-photo-library-or-device-camera-via-uiimagepickerc)

In iOS 10. You have to set privacy Setting for Camera & Photo Library. Camera & Photo Privacy Setting at info.Plist

This solved my crashing issue!