# iOS 10 - App crashes To access photo library or device camera via UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, xcode8

Below is my code to access photo library

```
-(void)click_gallery
{

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
     {

    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255 green:127.0/255 blue:244.0/255 alpha:1];
    [imgPicker.navigationBar setTintColor:color];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:NO completion:Nil];
     }

}
```

And it aborts with

**This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x109955efc <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x109955f01 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x109955f04 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x109955f06 <+10>: jae    0x109955f10               ; <+20>
    0x109955f08 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x109955f0b <+15>: jmp    0x1099507cd               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x109955f10 <+20>: retq   
    0x109955f11 <+21>: nop    
    0x109955f12 <+22>: nop    
    0x109955f13 <+23>: nop
```

And I get **Thread 10:EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION code=exc_i386_invop**,
Same code was working fine in iOS 9. Can someone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **iOS 10**. You have to set privacy Setting for Camera & Photo Library.

**Camera :**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

**Photo Library:**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

Answer (score 1):

> IOS 10 Now Requires User Permission to Access Media Library, Photos,
>   Camera and other Hardware like these. The solution for this is to add
>   their keys into info.plist with description for user that how we are
>   using their data , iOS already required permissions to access
>   microphone, camera, and media library earlier (iOS6, iOS7), but since
>   iOS10 the apps will crash if you don't provide the description why you
>   are asking for the permission.

Add below key value in plist file.

There is a list of all Cocoa Keys that you can specify in your Info.plist file

**Photo :**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

**Microphone :**

```
Key        :  Privacy - Microphone Usage Description    
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use
```

**Camera :**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```