# Is it possible to call the System Camera from my own app

Tags: ios, ios-camera

I want to call the System Camera from my app by "openURL", is it possible?

I have read the document [About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html). It mentions Main, Phone .etc, but do not mention Camera. As I can open the Setting Application by "UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString" which is also not mentioned, so I not sure the camera can not be open like that the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any URL Schemes for the camera app since Apple is providing an API instead to show the camera from within your own application by using `UIImagePickerController`, especially `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

If you are just looking to open a camera you can use this API. You can find an example to use this class here: [Example Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018529/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-not-working-swift).